# MatToQImage QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap

Tags: opencv, qpixmap

I Try to display a video processed by OpenCV, which is in Mat format, to a Qt self-defined FrameLabel. Mat frames can be populated when I add the OpenCV function **imshow("frame",mat)**, but turn to the *QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap* after I removed the imshow("frame",mat). Even trying to lock the thread not solve the problem. I have done some search, found that it might due to QPixmap resource should be defined in something like "xxx.qrc".
My code is as below:

```
void IntelligentSurveillance::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    QMutex processingMutex;
    string filename = VIDEO_PATH;
    VideoCapture cap;

    cap.open(filename);
    Mat mat;
    QImage qImage;

    for (;;)
    {
        cap >> mat;
        //processingMutex.lock();
        qImage = MatToQImage(mat);
        //processingMutex.unlock();

        ui.frame->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qImage).scaled(ui.frame->width(), ui.frame->height(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio));

        //imshow("frame", mat);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }}
```

Output always like: *QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap*

The problem is that it works fine when I add **imshow("frame",mat)**...

Can anyone give some help? Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

You need to use temp variable to save image, for example

```
QPixmap icon = QPixmap(":/img/" + iconFileName);
QPixmap tmp = icon.scaled(30, 30, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
value = tmp;
```

And this message gone!